# Show suggestions for AutoCompleteTextView from an XML file

Tags: android, xml, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView in which I have to show suggestions from data in an XML file. Is it possible to do so, or will I have to convert this XML into JSON format?

Structure of my XML file-

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <elements>
        <elem>
            <name>Name 1</name>
            <code>2001</code>
            <dat>1001</dat>
        </elem>
        <elem>
            <name>Name 2</name>
            <code>2002</code>
            <dat>1002</dat>
        </elem>
        .
        .
        .
        <elem>
           <name>Name 3</name>
           <code>2003</code>
           <dat>1003</dat>
        </elem>
    </elements>
```

The program has to look for matches in all three fields- `name`, `code` and `dat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AutoCompleteTextView` needs an adapter that will supply the data and the views. You should parse the XML file (by using an XML parser like `SAXParser`, etc) and convert it into an `ArrayList` of objects and then use the `ArrayList` as the backing data for the adapter.

XML or JSON depends on whether or not the data will be modified. XML is good if the data will later be modified by the user. JSON is good for keeping snapshot data that will not change.